# How do I add up a object in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JSON, and I want to know how I can add a value to an object.

Here is my code:

```
var text = '{"coins":"500"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML =
obj.coins + "500"; (<-- This one does not work)
```

Comment: A string is not a number. Use `parseInt()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "This one does not work". If you have html element with id of "coins" it will display "500500" in it..

Comment: @msmolcic yes this was the problem, but now its solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```js
var text = '{"coins":"500"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = parseInt(obj.coins, 10) + 500;
```

```html
<span id="coins"></span>
```

If you want to use with a button, you can try with this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var text = '{"coins":"500"}';
  var obj = JSON.parse(text);
  document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = parseInt(obj.coins, 10);

  var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton"); // Get the button context.
  myButton.addEventListener("click", function() { // Assign the click event to your button.
    document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = parseInt(obj.coins, 10) + 750;
  });
};
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
<span id="coins"></span>
```

The unobtrusive way is by using an id in your code and using `addEventListener` function in your code.

<kbd>[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/dwrt5omm/)</kbd>

Comment: I have another question, but stackoverflow wont let me ask once again, so I post this here: How can I make a button that each time its clicked its add up to my saved var text?

Comment: Here is the code:var text = '{"coins":"500"}';
JS:
var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = parseInt(obj.coins, 10);



function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = parseInt(obj.coins, 10) + 750;
}
HTML:   <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

Comment: You might try with `addEventListener` function. I'm gonna update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var text = '{"coins":"500"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML =
obj.coins + +"500";
```

But using parseInt("500") instead of +"500" is a cleaner way to do what you want.

Comment: the one with + + did not worked as expected, with parseInt everything worked :)